# Selenium - Java - ChromeDriver: Opens blank "data;" on some cases before opening another chrome window that runs actual test?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm an intern who was tasked with developing various test cases with Selenium. For the most part what I've developed works, however:

For some of my test cases a blank "data;" window opens up and then it'll open another window with my actual test case running. It doesn't really impede on my test case from functioning, but gets annoying from all the extra windows it's opening.

I've searched stackoverflow as well as other forums thoroughly and some people found solutions from updating the chromedriver (which I did and didn't work) and the questions others have posted here are in regards to their actual test case window being a blank data; instead of the issue I'm having.

**Relevant Information:**

- I'm using JUnit and in my @Before annotation I instantiate the chrome
  driver object as I close the driver after every case (to be able to
  run each case independently even if they're in the same test class).

**This extra blank data; window seemed to only come up after I did the above point.**

- I do a driver.get(URL) within each test case at the beginning

If someone has a solution can they please post and perhaps explain why it's behaving this way as I don't just want the solution, but want to understand the underlying cause behind it.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: As I've mentioned before many questions posted are similar, but not the same issue I am having. The link you've stated here leads to a user having his main window a blank data; solution: update chromedriver. 

My issue is different I am getting 2 windows open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New blank "data" window opens when new ChromeDriver() is created. So if you see two windows, that means new ChromeDriver() was executed twice.

You might have left some ***driver = new ChromeDriver();*** in the code somewhere, before you created your ***@Before*** method.

So when you are running your test, you have this code (***driver = new ChromeDriver();***) executed twice. Once in @Before method, and then again somewhere else in code.

Try using search in your IDE to find all occurrences of ***new ChromeDriver()***.

Or if not, maybe somehow your @Before method executes twice. New blank "data" window opens when new ChromeDriver() is created. So if you see two windows, that means new ChromeDriver() was executed twice.

Comment: I thought that was the issue, eventually after looking everywhere I couldn't find it. But once you reinforced to me that was indeed the issue I had a second look. Turns out in the parent class for the test classes had driver = new ChromeDriver(); in the @BeforeClass.Thanks so much and definitely will take a look into your Udemy course and send it off to my friend who's looking to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Try verbose logging to at least see if it's the same instance of chromedriver opening up two windows.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
```

If it's separate chromedriver instances, you'll see, on Windows, in Task Manager two instances of chromedriver.exe, on Mac in Activity Monitor, two instances in chromedriver. Then you can narrow it down to maybe one of your test cases doesn't actually run, or immediately fails.